# Pointer to a void

Tags: c++

```
inline int cmp (const void *a, const void *b)
{
  int aa = *(int *)a;
  int bb = *(int *)b;
  return (aa < bb) ? -1 : (aa > bb) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

This is a rather simple function that returns -1 if a is less than b, 0 if they are equal, and 1 if a is greater than b.

What are the properties of `const void *`? As I understood `*(int *)a` casts `a` to a pointer to an `int` and retrieves its content, and `const void *` points to memory that should not be modified while `void *` points to memory that could be modified,
but what does it mean to point to a `void`? It is not like pointing to an `int` for example. I don't think I'm being clear. I just don't get the concept of pointing to a `void`. Can you help?

Comment: Roughly, "pointing to `void`" is the same thing as "pointing to anything".

Comment: `void` has two meanings: 1. a function accepts or returns nothing and 2. when paired with `*` a pointer to memory of unknown type.

Comment: I wouldn't use this function. C++ features such as templates make void pointers rarely necessary. Unless dealing with low-level memory, I've never needed a void pointer.

Comment: Also this smells like old C. In C++ you can do better, for example something like `template<typename T> inline int cmp(T const& a, T const& b) { return (a < b) ? -1 : (b < a) ? 1 : 0; }` (and call it with actual objects, not pointers to them). _Edit: Neil Kirk was faster :)_

Comment: const T * a // not T const& a , no?

Comment: @NewProgrammer No. `T const& a`, or `const T& a` if you prefer (exactly the same here), a _reference to constant `T`_. You tagged as C++, C++ has pointers like C but it has also references you know?

Comment: you are passing by reference instead of by pointer, same answer though thank you what got me wondering was the const void pointer

Comment: Correcting my previous comment (now deleted): Another way to write that return statement: `return (aa > bb) - (aa < bb);` (thanks @gx_)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, `void *` means "points at something, not quite sure what". This is much more of a C style solution. In C++, I'd say the correct solution is:

```
template<typename T>
int cmp(const T *a, const T *b)
{
    return (*a < *b)? -1 : (*a > *b) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

or without pointers:

```
template<typename T>
int cmp(const T a, const T b)
{
    return (a < b)? -1 : (a > b) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

However, the C style solution may be useful in cases where you'd be using it for "C" style functions (`qsort` comes to mind - although in that particular case, I'd say `std::sort` is a better choice anyway).

Comment: Wouldn't `a` and `b` not better be declared as references in the second snippet?

Comment: @AdamS: Well, if `T` is a "large" type (at least bigger than about `2 * sizeof(size_t)`), it's faster to copy it. Otherwise it is not. In a C++ implementation, templates gets inlined [at least in simple functions like this one], and as a consequence, any copying of the inputs is probably not going to affect things anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`void *` is used as a pointer to anything, where the type it points to is unknown or does not matter. By casting it to `int *` you are making the assumption that they point to integers, which may be true in your use case, for example when passing a pointer to this function as a comparator for a collection of `int`s.

Note that casting to `int *` from `const void *` is bad style and should be avoided, cast to `const int *` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`void *a`

`void *b`

Are generic pointer, its used in order to make the function generic, i.e. it can operate on any data type

Such prototype are used for `qsort`

`int (*compar)(const void*,const void*)` as a custom comparator

However in actual defining while comparison you still need to know the data type in advance.

As in your case  they are of type `int`

Comment: But the function uses them as ints.

Comment: What's the advantage over `const int *` or even just `int`?

Comment: you mean this is a possible alternative to using templates?

Comment: @NeilKirk - no, the function uses them as `int*`.

Comment: @NewProgrammer Yes, but it's strange as it then assumes the pointers are ints.

Comment: @PeteBecker Then dereferences them to get an int, making an assumption about what it points to. So I don't understand why it doesn't just use int pointers in the parameters.

Comment: @NeilKirk - right, it assumes that the pointers point to `int` values. In this limited example that's pointless, but that `cmp` function is passed as an argument to `qsort`, which can sort arbitrary types, so it is written entirely in terms of `void*`. When you're sorting `int` values, the comparison function should compare `int` values; when you're sorting `double` values, the comparison function should compare `double` values, etc. But because it's used as an argument to `qsort` it has to take `void*`.

Comment: @NewProgrammer - if the pointers passed to this function don't point to `int` the function will not work correctly. When you use a function like this with `qsort`, the first argument to `qsort` is a `const void*` that points to the data to be sorted; the last argument is a pointer to a function that takes two `const void*` arguments and treats them as pointers to the data type that's being sorted. So when sorting an array of `int`, the comparison function casts the `void*` pointers to `int*`; when sorting an array of `double`, the comparison function casts the `void*` pointers to `double*`.

Answer (score 0):

Void pointers can be typecasted to any type of pointer. Or void pointers just point to a memory location without knowing what type it points to.

Comment: You can't portably cast (not "typecast") a `void*` pointer to a function pointer, though it does work on most systems.